# Find the roots of $ (a - x)^2 + b^2 = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I Find the roots of $ (a - x)^2 + b^2 = 0 $ ?

I just play with the numbers but I don't arrive to any smart conclusion. If $ x = a $ or $ x= -a$, then $(a-x)^2 = -b^2$. But that is not the root of the polyomial...

Comment: Real roots? If $b\ne 0$ there aren't any.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use complex numbers then $a-x=\pm b i$ and $x=a\pm b i$.

If you are looking for real solutions only, then if $b\not=0$ no real solutions exist. If $b=0$ then $x=a$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a - x)^2 + b^2 = 0$$
$$(a - x)^2 = -b^2$$
$$a - x = \pm b\sqrt{-1} = \pm bi \implies x = a \pm bi$$
These are the two roots, but both are complex.